# TypeError: db.collection is not a function Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

> TypeError: db.collection is not a function Firestore

I was presented this error in an attempt to import Firestore from the Firebase Admin SDK. Can't find anything that helped, or if I imported it incorrectly

Code; index.js (main file)

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./firebase/key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var db = admin.firestore()
```

Code; validate.js (import)

```
var db = require('../../../index')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just imported the Admin SDK, the syntax has changed to be modular. Check the latest documentation on [initializing Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_1) which shows how to initialize Firestore with the new `getFirestore` top-level function:

```
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
...
const db = getFirestore();
```